# Checkbox Value of Array in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am passing array into my view using checkbox input field. How can i get that array `accesses[value][value]` in my view with `value="1" or "0"`. I am also using `request.POST.getlist('accesses')` in my view but it is giving me value then how can i get array. Example - `accesses[3][25]` values.

Template.html

```
<input type="checkbox" name="accesses[3][25]" value="1" checked autocomplete="off">
<input type="checkbox" name="accesses[2][15]" value="1" autocomplete="off">
<input type="checkbox" name="accesses[4][95]" value="1" autocomplete="off">
<input type="checkbox" name="accesses[5][10]" value="1" checked autocomplete="off">
```

View.py

```
def AclView(request):
   accesses = request.POST.getlist('accesses')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django does not parse `[]` from field names to build lists (like PHP does, if I remember correctly). To get a list of values, you have to submit same under the same key. Try this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="accesses" value="1" checked autocomplete="off">
<input type="checkbox" name="accesses" value="1" autocomplete="off">
<input type="checkbox" name="accesses" value="1" autocomplete="off">
<input type="checkbox" name="accesses" value="1" checked autocomplete="off">

def AclView(request):
   accesses = request.POST.getlist('accesses')
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a list called accesses, you have four individual inputs called "accesses[3][25]" etc. So to should use those names to access them.